# Meteor.js errors on the client console

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

What does this error mean? I have a bunch of them in a bundled version of my meteor app.

```
Exception from Deps afterFlush function: TypeError: Cannot read property '_spark_y3zPMfQWJhDD6vSoY' of null
```

Comment: Can you give us the code in context? The error should throw a line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually comes up when you move some Meteor rendered DOM elements using non-Meteor code (i.e. jQuery). Then, when Meteor goes to look for those DOM elements after a reactivity change, it can't find them and complains.

Comment: @David no, but it means you're probably not using Meteor properly in conjunction with another library. You may also see reactive computations fail to update properly.

Comment: Something intersting is that I am getting this error after the meteor bundle, I don't get it when I run the meteor project using the meteor command.